# Circular Reference Delphi vs C#

Tags: c#, delphi, circular-reference

I am trying to make some class relationships in Delphi.

In other languages like C#, PHP and etc. I have no problems with these relationships, but in Delphi I have a circular reference error.

Why does this error happen in Delphi and not in C#? How and why can other languages handle circular reference and Delphi not? How does C# handle this?

Is there any solution for Delphi without using interface or single unit?

### Delphi

#### Dad.pas

```
unit Dad;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections, Child;

type
  TDad = class
  private
    { private declarations }
    FName: string;
    FChildren: TObjectList<TChild>;
  protected
    { protected declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Children: TObjectList<TChild> read FChildren write FChildren;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

#### Child.pas

```
unit Child;

interface

uses
  Dad;

type
  TChild = class
  private
    { private declarations }
    FName: string;
    FDad: TDad;
  protected
    { protected declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Dad: TDad read FDad write FDad;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

### CSharp

#### Dad.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using CircularReferenceTest.SecondNamespace;

namespace CircularReferenceTest.FirstNamespace
{
    public class Dad
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Child.ps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using CircularReferenceTest.FirstNamespace;

namespace CircularReferenceTest.SecondNamespace
{
    public class Child
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Dad Dad { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: No, there are no other solutions besides using single unit or interfaces.

Comment: Delphi has single pass compiler, C# does not [How Many Passes?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/02/04/how-many-passes/)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar There kinda is another solution although it isn't most pretty one. And that is deriving both TDad and TChild classes from a common class that is declared in a separate unit. Then you have both Dad.pas and Child.pas including that common unit in interface section and each other in implementation section. And the ugly thing is that you might have to be typecasting some things in implementation section when dealing with children. But there is an advantage in the recommended approach. And that is that TDad class can eventually have another TDad class as one of its children